# json-server returns TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, json-server

I just installed json-server and ran it, then I got an error.

db.json

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "John"
  }
}
```

a part of package.json

```
    "scripts": {
      "json-server": "json-server --watch db.json -port 5000"
    },
```

I ran `npm run json-server` and I got

```
> myproject@0.1.0 json-server
> json-server --watch db.json -port 5000


  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Loading true
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received type boolean (true)
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:10)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:467:35)
    at /Users/admin/project/myproject/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/run.js:118:32 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1287) but these solutions didn't work for me. Some people say use the latest react-scripts, so I use the latest one.

### Environment

- macOS 12.5
- TypeScript 4.8.4
- React 18.2.0
- react-scripts 5.0.1
- json-server 0.17.0

Thank you to read, can anyone solve it?

Comment: I believe you have made an error in your command: `"json-server": "json-server --watch db.json -port 5000"` you use a simple dash, where a double dash is required, for the `--port` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Starting json-server with sudo privileges made it run